# How to use testRestTemplate for a post request with no request body

Tags: spring-boot, post, uri, integration-testing, resttemplate

I have a rest endpoint as below:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/customers/{customerId}")
public SomeResponse manageCustomers(@PathVariable  String customerId){
...
}
```

This endpoint picks customer data from one system for the given customerId and saves it in another system. Thus, it doesn't require any request body.

I need to write an integration test for this. When I use testRestTemplate for this, I can't find a good enough method where I can pass requestEntity as null. Whenever I do that, I get an exception saying 'uriTemplate must not be null'.

I have tried to use 'postForObject', 'exchange' methods but doesn't work. Any ideas?

Below is my IT:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironmentSpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@DirtiesContext
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class CustomerIT extends Specification{

@LocalServerPort
private int port;

@Autowired
private TestRestTemplate restTemplate

def "should get customer from first system and save in second system"() {

    given:
    def customerUrl = new URI("http://localhost:" + port + "/customers/1234")
    def expected = new SomeObject(1)

    when:
    def someObject =
            restTemplate.postForEntity(customerUrl, null, SomeObject.class)

    then:
    someObject != null
    someObject == expected
}
}
```

Comment: If `expected`, `secondSystemMockUrl` and `uriTemplate` is `null` I'd start by figuring out why that is the case. Could you perhaps create a second IT that mimics the minimal one I wrote without all the extra stuff? Even if you don't stub the secondSystem you would maybe end up with a different exception?

Comment: I removed all the wiremock stuff and tried to run it again to see if it atleast reaches the controller but I still get the same exception of uriTemplate being null. Let me know if you think of something, but thanks anyways for taking a look.

Comment: Perhaps you could post the stripped down IT?

Comment: Edited my post with the minimal IT.

Comment: Just a couple of things to try. 1) Remove `@Autowired` and just `new` the `restTemplate`. 2) `customerUrl` from `URI` to `String` and 3) remove the `@DirtiesContext` - and maybe even the `@ActiveProfiles("test")`. I'm really not expecting any of this to make a difference, but just to strip everything down. And maybe look into how scopes of whatever test framework you're using - I'm not familiar with it. Extremely far fetched but maybe the `given:` scope isn't available in the `when:` scope

Answer (score 0):

Using `postForEntity(url, null, ResponseType.class)` works for me.

My postmapping is equal to your except for the responseType. I used `Map` just as an example

```
@PostMapping(value = "/customers/{customerId}")
public Map<String, String> manageCustomers(@PathVariable String customerId){
    return new HashMap<String, String>(){{ put("customerId", customerId); }};
}
```

Test to verify that it works

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class CustomerControllerTest {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    private final TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate = new TestRestTemplate();

    @Test
    public void postEmptyBodyShouldReturn200OK() {
        String customerId = "123";
        ResponseEntity responseEntity = testRestTemplate
                .postForEntity(format("http://localhost:%s/ping/customers/%s", port, customerId), null, Map.class);
        assertThat(responseEntity.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK);
        assertThat(responseEntity.getHeaders().getContentType()).isEqualTo(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);
        assertThat(responseEntity.getBody()).isNotNull();
        assertThat(((LinkedHashMap) responseEntity.getBody()).size()).isEqualTo(1);
        assertThat(((LinkedHashMap) responseEntity.getBody()).get("customerId")).isEqualTo(customerId);
    }
}
```

Running this test in maven

```
$ mvn -Dtest=CustomerControllerTest test

    (...removed unnecessary output...)

[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 4.137 s - in com.ins.example.demo.rest.CustomerControllerTest
10:04:54.683 [Thread-3] INFO  o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor - Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  6.940 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-04-07T10:04:55+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same exception. I have updated my question with my integration test. Could you please take a look?